# Refused to display, set X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, x-frame-options

I have a very old site built in ASP .Net 2008 by an external team who I have no contact with. All of a sudden a page doesn't seem to render properly in Chrome and FireFox but works fine with other browsers. The page is set with an iFrame.

Looking under Inspect Element (Chrome) for the page failing to render I see the error

```
Refused to display 'http://www.example.com/somepage.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.
```

So read a few articles and I may not understand this fully but it seems to me the error is, the domain requested will NOT allow itself to be displayed within a frame.

The URL above is not the URL I am familiar with (i.e. its third party, I don't have any control with it). Is there anyway to resolve this or is this purely the owner of the domain would have to allow? IF so why does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to resolve this

Not at your end.

> or is this purely the owner of the domain would have to allow?

This

> IF so why does it work in other browsers?

Speculating a little here, but `SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN` is not a valid value. It looks like Chrome is attempting error recovery and treating it as `SAMEORIGIN`

Comment: If the site to be embedded is ours. then how to fix it. please help. I have full control over the web site to be embedded. How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

[Quentin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290966/1178314) summaries it well.

In addition, if it is an external site beyond your control, they may have good reasons to forbid framing. (Like preventing [click-jacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet).)

They may also have included a [`Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self'` header](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors) which would have the same effect.

(And currently, a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510423) in Chromium (and Chrome) causes [`X-Frame-Options`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) to take precedence over `Content-Security-Policy` while it should not.)

You may hack that if their site is served over `http` (not `https`) and you have control of a common network device through which all your users network traffic to this site must go. I mean, on that device, if it does allow you to do so, you may filter out 'undesired' headers from responses of this site.

Of course, this is a debatable hack. Depending on terms of uses of the 'victim' site, it could even be a legal issue to do so.

Comment: If the site to be embedded is ours. then how to fix it. please help. I have full control over the web site to be embedded. How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: If it is yours, adjust it for ensuring it does not emit any `X-Frame-Options` or `Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors` http headers. Or adjust those headers to allow your other site. And better ask a new question on stackoverflow if needed, comments are not suitable for Q&A.

Comment: im creating an app that allows users to select a url which will be displayed in an `iframe`. since i dont know what websites they will want to visit, is there a workaround the `X-Frame-Options` stuff, so that the users website loads no matter what??

Comment: Of course, no, there is no workaround I know of! Otherwise that workaround would defeat the very purpose of this instruction, and would be indeed a security flaw in the browsers for which the work-around would work. Rather than sharing it for use, I would report it as a security bug to impacted browsers.